# What is the Symfony equivalent to php command session_write_close?

Tags: php, ajax, symfony

I have been experiencing the same problem [these developers mentioned](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!msg/symfony-users/5WBMyNtpxUQ/d3D8ofi0o4cJ) where session locking holds a page up while a long-running Ajax request completes. I can solve the problem using `session_write_close()` but I am unclear on the relationship between the Symfony session objects we use elsewhere and this pure PHP command.  I am worried using this one PHP command while using Symfony session everywhere else will cause some instability.

I assumed it was the same as `$session->save()` but using `$session->save()` does not fix the blocking problem the way `session_write_close()` does.

```
//pseudo code
session_write_close();
//do some ajax stuff
$session = $this->get('session');
$session->start();
```

Comment: can you run a `var_dump(session_status())` after `$session->save()`, and post the output?

Comment: `$session->save()` appears to use the `NativeSessionStorage/SessionStorageInterface ` class to save the data, my money is on that function.

Comment: @Federkun I think it returns void https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/master/Session/Session.php

Comment: @Scuzzy That was my initial thought too. But it does not resolve the blocking.

Comment: hmm, I had a look at https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/master/Session/Storage/NativeSessionStorage.php and I can see that it's save functon does call `session_write_close()` in a try block. I wonder if it's worth manually debugging this in your project to see if its gets called.

Comment: @Scuzzy I guess I'm going to have to. I guess it answers my question about if the two sessions are related though,

Comment: Couldn't you just inject the Symfony session and call `save()` on that?

Comment: @Gun5m0k3 I tried that, but it doesn't fix the locking...

Comment: In the end, we just had to use the native call and it worked.